# Como descobrir se um número é subnúmero

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de um código,com explicação (se possível é claro), para saber se um número é sub número de outro.
Exemplo:

> P=101
>   Q=100001010057

Logo `P` é sub número de `Q`. Grato desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso:

```
>>> str(101) in str(100001010057)
True

>>> str(18) in str(100001010057)
False
```

Você converte seus 2 números para string e utiliza o operador `in` nativo de Python, que procura uma substring dentro de uma string. Mais genérico:

```
str(P) in str(Q)
```

Comment: Nossa,havia feito um código com mais de 20 linhas,bem mais complicado.

Comment: Muito obrigado,é de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Com o método `find` você pode verificar se a ocorrências na `string` alvo, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
if '101'.find(str(011001101)): 
    print('101 eh sub numero de 011001101')
```

Converti para `string` o numero `011001101` e em seguida pesquisei pelo numero `101` através do método find passando como parâmetro a sequencia de numero que é a string alvo que converti.

Implementação com variáveis:

```
P = '101'
Q = '100001010057'

if P.find(Q):
    print("P eh sub numero de Q")
```

Lebre-se que o método `find` é um método do módulo **string.py** ou seja, ele só funciona com strings, se tiver um inteiro sera necessário converte-lo para string como foi feito no exemplo acima.

Fonte: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Se não entender algo, deixe um comentário que eu acrescento mais informações.